# Как правильнее сделать адаптив?

Tags: html, css

Делал адаптив сайта и впал в ступор, а именно как лучше дальше сделать. Макет адаптивной версии меня так же вгоняет в ступор, потому что дизайн там кривой и не понятный. В макете, как я понял, нужно скрыть блок .services-info, но это уже на мобильных экранах, а как поступить на экранах планшетных размеров?

**Данная секция называется .services**

Сам сайт cn76553.tmweb.ru/

Весь код jsfiddle.net/a3c5qkyo/

Макет [www.figma.com/file/5H4KxRfSDOpqoOo3iNPDqc/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1](http://www.figma.com/file/5H4KxRfSDOpqoOo3iNPDqc/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

образец адаптива из макета
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такие вoпросы уточняются-обсуждаются с дизайнером и/или заказчиком. Мы ведь не можем залезть к ним в головы и извлечь оттуда ответ.

Comment: Общий совет: не делать то, чего не требуется / воздержаться от излишней суеты в работе. После первичной реализации, обычно следует приемка - вот в ее процессе, и стоит указать на недоработки макета, или внести свои предложения. До приемки, разумнее следовать макету/ТЗ. Вообще, имхо есть всего две точки наиболее успешного взаимодействия "руководитель-исполнитель": 1. до начала работ; 2. после их завершения (судя по вопросу, первая уже пропущена, значит остается вторая).